# How to transform a series of scalar variables to a vector variable?

Tags: functions, vector, variable

Say a function is set:

```
a := Sum[b[i], {i, 8}]
```

As can be seen that `b[i]` is a scalar variable.

Now I want to transform the scalar variables of `b[i]` to a vector variable `t:={b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8]}`, and it can be used in the function mentioned above.

And more, `t` should be able to replace by specific vector, say `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`, which can be substituted into `a`, and get the desired result `36`.

And that means `b[1]->1` `b[2]->2` `b[3]->3` `b[4]->4` `b[5]->5` `b[6]->6` `b[7]->7` `b[8]->8`, and they can be substituted into `a`, so `a=Sum[i,{i,8}]=36`. But it is done in one step, something like this `{b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8]}->{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`.
How should I accomplish such a procedure?

Comment: Do you just want to create a function `a[b_]:=Total@b` and then evaluate `a[{1,2,3,4}]`?

Comment: No, I need transform scalar variables `b[i]` to a vector variable `{b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8]}`. And it can be replaced by another vector with the same length. NOT just summation.@Edmund

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html)? Using it we get: `a = Sum[Indexed[t, i], {i, 8}] (* Indexed[t, {1}] + Indexed[t, {2}] + Indexed[t, {3}] + 
 Indexed[t, {4}] + Indexed[t, {5}] + Indexed[t, {6}] + 
 Indexed[t, {7}] + Indexed[t, {8}] *)`, then we can do: `a /. t -> Range@8 (* 36 *)`.

Comment: When defining a function, you should specify what variables it depends on. Do you know about `Total`? How is your function different from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but this may help.
To convert `a` into a list (or "vector") you can use `Apply`, i.e.

```
t = List@@a
(* {b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8]} *)
```

You can substitute values into `a` using

```
a /. Thread[t -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]
(* 36 *)
```

### Addendum

Following up your comment. I am still unsure what you are trying to achieve. As others have suggested, `Total` is pretty much the thing that does what your `a` may be supposed to do. You could write

```
a[vec_] := Total[vec]
```

and

```
t = {b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6], b[7], b[8]};
```

Then

```
a[t]
(* b[1] + b[2] + b[3] + b[4] + b[5] + b[6] + b[7] + b[8] *)
```

and

```
a[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]
(* 36 *)
```

Comment: It does solve the problem mentioned above, but not the way I want. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand what you are looking for, then. Why do you specify `a := Sum...` in this way, as an assignment without any variables?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have found a alternate way to achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list:

```
c = Table[b[i], {i, 8}];

a[c_List] := blah-blah
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The List created should be able to be assigned to a specific vector and substituted into function `a`